# Converting null object Gson to Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been using Google's Gson API for quite some time and love its simplicity.

Nonetheless, I've found (probably) a bug on the `toJson` method.

When I try to convert a `null` object to `JSON`, instead of an exception, or alternatively a `null` String return, I get a `String` with the value `null`.

Do you consider this a bug?

Comment: There is no such thing as a _null object_. `null` is the literal value for the [null type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7). It's just a reference value, not an object.

Comment: How can it be a "bug" if it's valid JSON.  See json.org & review the JSON syntax.

Comment: It depends on how you have annotated these fields. You either get a null or you get a "safe" non-null object that indicates that the serialized/deserialized object is or was null. See https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support It's up to you which one you want, and write your code to handle this accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is not producing `NullPointerException` while converting because it is literal and it is valid Gson Value.

Comment: I understand that. But if I instatiate Gson class like:
Gson gson = new Gson()
… and the object that I am serializing has global variables with null TYPE, those variables aren't serialized.

But if I instantiate Gson class like:
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()
... The global variables with null TYPE, those variables are serialized.

Therefore, despite “null” being a valid JSON string, since I instantiated Gson like new Gson() in my opinion I should get at least an empty string

Comment: It will not given empty string because It considers `null` as literal.

Comment: The fact that it is a literal means nothing. _literal_ is a language concept.

Answer (score 2):

No, [`null`](http://json.org/) is a [valid JSON value.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-3)